# Sharepoint Excel Error IE9 - Workbook is larger than the maximum workbook size allowed to be opened in the browser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, excel

A few of my users who are using ie9 for a SharePoint housing a few excel files around 19mb are experiencing a recent issue where they cannot see 'read-only or edit' options; (this is enabled to open in client application through SharePoint settings). The error they get is `"Workbook is larger than the maximum workbook size allowed to be opened in the browser."` as soon as they click it. I did a normal google search and found a fix in regards to the farm central admin to increase the size from 10mb to at least 50mb. But What got me scratching my head is that this opens fine in IE8, just IE9 is presenting this error.

Any thoughts on a different workaround? Central admin ticket I feel may be a long turn around time for SharePoint IT to enable it for my site.

Comment: what is the size of the file? also try to open the IE9 in comparability mode.

Comment: Size of the file is 17.3mb

Answer (score 0):

You can open the workbook imediately in Excel with the following workaround:

- Opend the version history (click on the down arrow and select version
  history)
- Copy the link to the youngest version (right click the date and
  select copy link address)
- Paste this in the "open file" dialog from Excel (ctrl-O, ctrl-P) and
  enter